# Why does std::cbegin return the same type as std::begin

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) shows this signature for `std::cbegin`:

```
template< class C >
constexpr auto cbegin( const C& c ) -> decltype(std::begin(c));
```

Shouldn't it return something like `C::const_iterator` instead?

Comment: I agree that the page might be a bit clearer on this and not let people reason on it (as done in the given answers).  Also, an explanation why cbegin was introduced (to guarantee constness and not just rely on the constness of the parameter) might help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`c` is a `const` reference, so `std::begin(c)` it will return whatever the `const` overload of `C::begin()` returns. For standard library types, this is a `const_iterator`. For an array type, it is a pointer to `const`.

Note that this relies on other, non-standard library user defined `C`, being implemented sanely with a `const` overload for `C::begin()` that returns an iterator that gives you `const` access to the container's elements.

Answer (score 3):

`std::begin` returns an `iterator` or a `const_iterator`, depending on the whether the argument is `const` or not, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin and the declaration of a member function `begin` for a standard container http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin

`std::cbegin` returns what `std::begin` returns (via `decltype`), so if you have a `const` object, the `const` overload is selected, which in turns returns a `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

cbegin is implemented like below :

```
template <class C>
auto cbegin(const C& container)->decltype(std::begin(container))
{
   return std::begin(container); // see explanation below
}
```

corresponding begin is as below .

```
template< class C > 
auto begin( C& c ) -> decltype(c.begin()); //calling container's begin
```

This cbegin template accepts any type of argument
representing a container-like data structure, C, and it accesses this argument
through its reference-to-const parameter, container. If C is a conventional container
type (e.g., a std::vector), container will be a reference to a const
version of that container (e.g., a const std::vector&). Invoking the nonmember
begin function (provided by C++11) on a const container yields a
const_iterator, and that iterator is what this template returns.

For example , if I have used vector as an argument to `cbegin` like below .

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::cbegin(v1);
```

Now , see how template deduction happened in this case , template(class C) is deduced to be vector and parameter of `cbegin` (const C& container) deduced to be `const vector<int> &` . Now since container is itself is constant , it will return constant version of begin of vector .

```
iterator begin();
const_iterator begin() const; //This will be used .
const_iterator cbegin() const;
```