# Why does std::cbegin() not call .cbegin() on the container?

Tags: c++

The following code fails the static assertion:

```
#include <gsl/span>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int theArr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    gsl::span<int> theSpan{ theArr, std::size(theArr) };

    using std::cbegin;
    auto it1 = cbegin(theSpan);
    auto it2 = theSpan.cbegin();
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(it1), decltype(it2)>);
}
```

This fails because `std::cbegin()` calls the `.begin()` method on a const ref of the container. For standard-defined containers, this returns a `const_iterator`, which is the same type that `.cbegin()` returns. However, `gsl::span` is a bit unique because it models a sort of "borrow type". A `const gsl::span` behaves like a const pointer; the span itself is const, but what it points-to is not const. Hence, the `.begin()` method on a `const gsl::span` still returns a non-const iterator, whereas explicitly calling `.cbegin()` returns a const iterator.

I'm curious as to why `std::cbegin()` was not defined as invoking `.cbegin()` on the container (which all standard containers seem to implement) to account for cases such as this.

This is somewhat related to: [Why does std::cbegin return the same type as std::begin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486309/why-does-stdcbegin-return-the-same-type-as-stdbegin)

Comment: [for reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) : "`auto cbegin( const C& c )` returns exactly `std::begin(c)`"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> this fails because `std::cbegin()` calls the `.begin()`

To be more precise, `std::cbegin` calls `std::begin`, which in the generic overload calls `c.begin`.

For what it's worth, it should be possible to fix `gsl::span` to return const iterator upon `std::cbegin` if the designers of gsl specify that there is a specialisation for the generic overload of `std::cbegin` for `gsl::span` that uses `c.cbegin` instead of `std::begin`, if that is the desired behaviour. I don't know their reasoning for not specifying such specialisation.

As for reasoning for why `std::cbegin` uses `std::begin`, I do not know for fact either, but it does have the advantage of being able to support containers that have a `c.begin` member, but not a `c.cbegin` member, which can be seen as a less strict requirement, as it can be satisfied by custom containers written prior to C++11, when there was no convention of providing a `c.cbegin` member function.

Comment: "std::span does propagate constness" - does it? It doesn't look like that to me from how the member functions are declared. Looking at P0122, it seems that not propagating constness was a design goal.

Comment: @bogdan you're right. I misread the member function declarations.

Answer (score 8):

First, note that, per [[tab:container.req]](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#tab:container.req):

> Expression: `a.cbegin()`
>
> Return type: `const_­iterator`
>
> Operational semantics: `const_­cast<​X const&​>(a)​.begin();`
>
> Complexity: constant

Therefore, `gsl::span` is not a container at all.  `cbegin` and `cend` are designed to  work with containers.  There are some exceptions (arrays, `initializer_list`) that require special care, but apparently the standard library cannot mention something like `gsl::span`.

Second, it is [LWG 2128](https://wg21.link/LWG2128) that introduced global `cbegin` and `cend`.  Let's see what the relevant part says:

> Implement `std::cbegin/cend()` by calling `std::begin/end()`. This has
>   numerous advantages:
>
> - It automatically works with arrays, which is the whole point of these non-member functions.
> - It works with C++98/03-era user containers, written before `cbegin/cend()` members were invented.
> - It works with `initializer_list`, which is extremely minimal and lacks `cbegin/cend()` members.
> - [container.requirements.general]
>     guarantees that this is equivalent to calling `cbegin/cend()` members.

Essentially, calling `std::begin/end()` save the work of providing special care for arrays and `initializer_list`.